# wp_mail - wordpress not sending mail

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to send mail to user inviting them to see the page which is password protected. My Code is :

```
function my_project_updated_send_email( $post_id ) {

    // If this is just a revision, don't send the email.
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;


    if ( post_password_required($post_id) ) {

        $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
        $post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
        $subject = 'New Report Published by MySelf';

        $email_to=$_POST["email_to"];
        $email_to = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $email_to);

        $password = $_POST["post_password"];
        $password = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $password);

        $message = "Here is the link for you on our website:\n\n";
        $message .= $post_title . ": " . $post_url . "\n\n";
        $message .= "Your Password is :" .$password;
        $headers = "From: ime@my.com";

        // Send email to admin.
        if( ($password!=="") || ($email_to!=="") ){
            wp_mail($email_to, $subject, $message, $headers );
        }

    }

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'my_project_updated_send_email' );
```

It doesn't send mail. Please advise.

Thanks,
Vikram

Comment: Where do you host your project? Do you run it on your local machine?

Comment: I think the mistake is here: 

    `if( ($password!=="") || ($email_to!=="") ){`

Replace the `||` by a `&&` because you want to assure that both are set.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned the comment in your code that you want to send email to the admin, On behalf of $_POST["email_to"] please use  get_option( 'admin_email' ).

eg.  $email_to=get_option( 'admin_email' );

Comment: Nah - It'll be sent to specific users only. email_to field is  added to Password protected option.

Comment: Test Mail from plugin **WP-Mail-SMTP** works well. So what could be the issue?